# Using documentApp Text class methods in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a range with rich text hyperlinks in it in a googlesheet, copied and pasted from elsewhere.

I want to create a function to extract the URLs - there's a method called .getLinkUrl in the text class that I think will do the trick.

However, SpreadsheetApp doesn't have a Text class, so I think I need the .getLinkUrl method from the Text class in DocumentApp.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
function getURL(range) {

   var textElement = DocumentApp.create("temp").getBody().editAsText()

   var url = textElement.setText(range.getValue()).getLinkUrl;

   return url

}
```

But you can't do that because you can't create documents in custom functions.

I'd really like to avoid having to use a triggered script or something instead of a function but I can't work out how to do it without.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, don't do this, because you'll end up with thousands of empty docs called temp >__<